# creating Django models one to one 'ish' relation to (read-only) legacy table

Tags: django, models, legacy

I'm working with default postgres database and a legacy database (MSSQL) which is read only (ro to me, data does change).

Understanding that there will be no keys or RI, is it possible to create a one-to-one 'like' relationship between a table in the read only legacy database and the default django database?

The MSSQL database has unmanaged models in the django project - Basically I want to reference objects in these models from regular models in django applications (with underlying django-managed tables).   Any suggestions on how to accomplish this or something with the same utility?

Is it possible to effect this sort of uninformed logical relationship with a custom field type?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the dialect you're using for your managed table? My gut feeling is this is not supported. See the docs on [limitations of cross-database relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases). (Edit: sorry I may have misunderstood; both these tables are on the same db?)

Comment: Thanks - I think you understand.  Per the link and my prev research I absolutely can NO create a onetoone relationship with a table in another databases, managed or not.  I need to funtionally emulate a OneToOne relationship, realizing I'll have no RI or keys to enforce it.